# Access global instance modified inside main() function of a server from different modules

Tags: python, global-variables

I have a server that contains a class which performs an expensive computation
during its initialization. I want to initialize this class once, inside the main() method of the server module, before starting the server. Then, I want other modules that import the server module to be able to retrieve the instance of this class.

Example (the sleep emulates the server running)

```
import time

# I want to store the shared_instance of this global variable
shared_instance = None


class Shared:
    def __init__(self):
        # Expensive computation that I only want to run once
        pass


def main():

    global shared_instance

    shared_instance = Shared()  # Now instance_of_scorer is not None anymore
    print(shared_instance)

    print("Starting server...")
    time.sleep(1000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run this server it prints:

```
<__main__.Shared object at 0x000001865A3C4320>
Starting server...
```

Now I have other module that should be able to see the instance:

```
import server

print(server.shared_instance)
```

However, shared_instance is not '<**main**.Shared object at 0x000001865A3C4320>' as expected. It is 'None'. Could you please tell me want I'm doing wrong and how can I solve this issue and achieve this functionality?.

Many thanks

Comment: Uh, are you aware of what `if __name__ == '__main__':` does? It makes *sure* nothing inside the if-body gets run if you import the module as a module, it will only be executed if you do `python my_module.py`, not if, in another module, you do `import my_module`

Comment: Hello, I though that after running the server, shared_instance was global across modules so I could get its updated value importing the server module. Is there any way to make shared_instance global across modules?. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to share state across multiple processes?

Comment: No, it is just an instance that takes a lot of time to create and that I want use in other modules

Comment: Um, then what do you mean "after the server is running ... I could get its updated value importing the server module"? So you run something like `python my_server_module.py`, and then what?

Comment: So first I do 'python my_server_module.py'. That generates the instance and the server starts running. Then, my use case would be an api call against the server which executes 'my_api_endpoint.py'. On this endpoint I need to use that instance that was created before starting the server because I don't want to recreate it on every api call

Comment: "api call against the server which executes 'my_api_endpoint.py'" what do you mean the api call ends up executing `my_api_endpiont.py`? As in subprocess?

Comment: I mean that I have something like

project
- server.py
- api_folder
-- api_endpoint1.py
-- api_endpoint2.py
-- api_endpoint3.py

Inside api_endpoint1.py I have functions to respond to GET, POST, etc.

So if I do a GET request like localhost:8888/api_endpoint1/, the get() function inside  api_endpoint1.py is triggered. Inside this get() function I need to call some functions from the Shared() class that resides in server.py, and I need an instance of Shared() that I want to retrieve from server.py so I don't need to recreate it again.

Comment: Right, I understand that you have a project structured over multiple files, but you are glossing over the important details: **how** does "the get() function inside api_endpoint" get triggered? You should elaborate as an edit to the question